# Looking for free Mac software to produce DVD's with subtitles

Tags: macos, dvd, burning, subtitles

I have a movie in .avi format and I created the subtitles, now I would like to create a DVD that can be reproduced on a "regular" dvd player.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

When you get a new mac it usually comes with an included copy of the current version of iLife, so you should have access to a version of iDVD, although it might not be the latest one.

You might need to convert the file to another format before you import it, but you should be able to do that with QuickTime, although you might need QuickTime pro.

Comment: Unfortunately, iDVD '11 still doesn't support subtitles. :(

Answer (score -1):

Hey, there, you may need to consider using a [DVD Creator Tool](http://www.imediacreator.com/howtoburn/burn-avi-to-dvd-on-mac.html#191), which is expected to solve your problem, hope this is useful for you.

Comment: It's not freeware...